# Search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android-studio

Few days ago I update android studio in 2.3.1. after that I face problem to search a string from whole project. After  press ctrl + shift + f open a dialog. but if i type string in textbox nothing shows in preview please check the screen for better understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQhD2.jpg)

Comment: have you checked **options** tab. is that all true in filters ?

Comment: All are unchecked now. but if i checked nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  eclipse Keymap  in settings, shortcut for searching a string  from whole project is  ctr+h.